# debugger; [ERROR] 194:11:identifier is a reserved word

Tags: javascript, jsrender

I add jsrender into my project, but when I made a deploy, sendme

```
> Errors found for public/js/xxxxxxxx/jsrender.js
>  > [ERROR] 194:11:identifier is a reserved word
>  > [ERROR] 1:0:Compilation produced 1 syntax errors.
```

this line made references to this var debugger;

¿How can I change the name without break the library?

Comment: Where did you get the package from?

Comment: I downloaded from github

Answer (score 1):

[`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) itself is a reserved word in Javascript and is commonly used for debugging, so you can't declare a variable with that name :

```
var debugger; // This doesn't work
debugger;     // This should work (common-use of debugger)
```

**Taking A Look Into jsrender.js**

Based off [looking at the assumed markup for `jsrender.js` for the line that you referenced](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/jsrender.js#L191-L200), it appears to just be a `debugger` call, which should work :

```
function dbgBreak(val) {
    // Usage examples: {{dbg:...}}, {{:~dbg(...)}}, {{dbg .../}}, {^{for ... onAfterLink=~dbg}} etc.
    try {
        debugger; // THIS IS THE LINE REFERENCED
        console.log("JsRender dbg breakpoint: " + val);
        throw "dbg breakpoint"; // To break here, stop on caught exceptions.
    }
    catch (e) {}
    return this.base ? this.baseApply(arguments) : val;
}
```

Based off of this, I don't see any reason that this specific line would cause a problem, unless there is some other syntax error that is present.

Comment: I investigate the function  debugger in js, but I look in the entire project and its not declare in other part, this error sendme a hook when i tried to make a commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "debugger" as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

JsRender does not declare a `var debugger;`. It looks like your error is thrown by a compile step. What software is outputting that error? What is your build/deploy process?

It may be that you are using YUICompressor, which has a related bug - and that the error is thrown by YUICompressor while minifying...? See https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/239. A workaround for your environment would be just to comment out `//debugger;` Doing so will not break anything.